# How...if any number x which ends in three is coprime to 10, then is 9x is also coprime to 10?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

why 9x? where did 9x come from?
It is probably some modulus arithmetic or Fermat-Euler theorem .... I just can't grasp it!!! Shame

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are both coprime to $10$, so is $a\times b$.